# Cannot get a reference to an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I have been banging my head up against the wall for several hours and I need help...

I want to be able to reference my JS in an external file rather than inline 
    @section Scripts
for an associated cshtml file.

I have tried both of the approaches below and none of them work.

```
@Html.RazorJSInclude("~/Scripts/Categories/Create.js");

        $.getScript("~/Scripts/Categories/Create.js", function ()
        {
            contentCategoriesCreate();
        });
```

The package RazorJSInclude just doesn't work as advertised. I don't see anywhere when debugging that this js file is pulled in.

No matter what I try with the jQuery getScript method, I cannot get it to resolve the url I am pointing to.

Note that with the latter, I did include a bundle in my Layout page and the Bundle.config file.

If I include the script inline, everything works fine, but I want to decouple the inline JS from my HTML.

What is the simplest way I can do this?

### EDIT

I included the Url.Content as suggested which I forgot to mention that I already tried. It didn't work (see screenshot).

[image]

I also tried the Razor Syntax: @Url.Content which also did not work. See below screenshot.
[image]

I don't know how something so simple to supposedly be able to do, is turning out to be a nightmare...

Any other suggestions would be helpful....

### EDIT 2

Lastly, what I have done, was to include the script inside my bundling. However, that still did not work. This time, the script loaded with no errors, but when I click on the "Create" button, the click function doesn't fire.

Here is pertinent code inside my BundleConfig.js file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jsViews").Include(
             "~/Scripts/Categories/Create.js",
             "~/Scripts/AntiForgeryToken.js"));
```

Here is pertinent code inside my _Layout.js file:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsViews")
```

Here is the pertinent code inside my Create.cshtml file:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        if (typeof contentCreateCategory == "function")
            contentCreateCategory();
    });
</script>
}
```

Here is the pertinent code inside my external JS file:

```
function contentCreateCategory()
{
    function contentCategoriesCreate()
    {
        $('#btnCategoryCreate').click(function (e)
        {
            var form = $('#form1');
            if (form.valid())
            {
                createCategory();
            }

            return false;
        });
    }
}

function createCategory()
{
    var category_Input = {
        CategoryDescription: $('#CategoryDescription').val()
    };

    var Url = $("#url").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        data: AddAntiCSRFToken(JSON.stringify(category_Input)),
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        async: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            // Record added
        },
        error: function (data, status, xhr)
        {
            alert(status + '\n' + xhr + '\n' + data);
        }
    });
};
```

Finally, here is the screenshot that proves the JS is loading, but nothing happens when I click the "Create" button. Note again, that when I include the script inline within the Create.cshtml file, everything works fine. I cannot do any more than what I've done. I've given the code & screenshots. I'm hoping *somebody* can please let me know what I need to do to get this to work...
[image]

Comment: Can't you just add a script tag?

Comment: the above code samples were included in script tags.

Comment: What I meant was you could use `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Categories/Create.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: This is the first time to see RazorJSInclude method is this an extension method created by you? also note JQuery will not resolve the delta so your URL should start by /

Comment: Please see my edits in response to your questions. Any help would be much appreciated....

Comment: I was able to get a reference to the file... The JS wasn't executing because I was executing the incorrect function name on the document.ready function...